# Parallax with background-position: center center without jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I couldn't think of a solution myself after trying dozens of approaches

```
#banner .slide {
    position: static;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-image: url(http://wp-content/uploads/2260-000-01.jpg);
}


#banner .slide {
    background-attachment: inherit;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

The background-image is positioned `center center` as you can see and it is intentional that the `background-attachement` is not `fixed` (as it would always in combination with cover lead to a to narrow view of the image.)

In order to achieve the desired parallax I use this snippet.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
        $('#banner .slide').css('background-position', 'center ' + $(window).scrollTop()*0.4 + 'px')
    })
```

The problem I have of course is that the initial scroll (very first change in scrollTop) leads to a jump of the image because of course JS does not know what `center` means for me.

So my goal is to keep the image position intially `center center` as I want to always  see the very vertical and horizontal cenver of the image.

Do you know any trick or idea how I could tell the JS the current vertical center of the image, so the parallax calculation would start from this point instead of starting from 0.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a slightly different approach by changing transform value of the slide instead.

```js
const parallaxables = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');

function runParallaxLoop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(runParallaxLoop);
    parallax();
}

function parallax() {
    parallaxables.forEach(parallaxable => {
        let distance = window.scrollY * 0.5;
        parallaxable.style.transform = `translate3d(0,-${distance}px, 0)`;
    });
}

runParallaxLoop();
```

```css
.parallax {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/sports/) no-repeat center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Every frame, you transform the element that needs to be parallaxed by a certain percentage of speed with which the browser is scrolling.

For this to work, you need the background-attachment of the parallax-able element to be fixed.

Comment: is there a way to make this work without background attachment fixed?

Comment: If you can use position fixed on the slide, that would be even better. Together with translate3d browser will be able to do the animation very cheaply without having to involve the main thread at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little bit old but I just wanted to throw an alternative way in that I have used in the past.  This is 100% vanilla javascript. One thing to note: you need to call init seperately inside the function so you don't get that ju

```js
let parallax = (id, rate) => {
  const parallaxObject = document.querySelector(id);
  const init = () => {
    const x = parallaxObject.getBoundingClientRect().top / rate;
    const y = Math.round(x * 100 / 100);
    parallaxObject.style.backgroundPosition = 'center ' + y + 'px';
  }
  init();
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    init();
  })
}



parallax('.hero', 5)
```

```css
.hero {
  background: #fff url('https://source.unsplash.com/random') no-repeat fixed center center / cover;
  margin-top: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
  min-height: 75vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <h1>Hero Text</h1>
  <div>
  
  
  // Scroll Down To See Effect
```